# Algorithm for predicting most likely items from lists of data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

Lets say I have N lists which are known. Each list has items, which may repeat (Not a set)
eg:

{A,A,B,C}, {A,B,C}, {B,B,B,C,C}

I need some algorithm (Some machine-learning one maybe?) which answers the following question:

Given a new & unknown partial list of items, for example, {A,B}, what is the probability that C will appear in the list based on the what I know from the previous lists. If possible, I would like a more fine-grained probability of: given some partial list L, what is the probability that C will appear in the list once, probability it will appear twice, etc... Order doesn't matter. The probability of C appearing twice in {A,B} should equal it appearing twice in {B,A}

Any algorithms which can do this?

Comment: Depends on the length of the list, I guess. For the rest: Markov.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good%E2%80%93Turing_frequency_estimation may be useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just pure mathematics, no actual "algorithms", simply estimate all the probabilities from your dataset (literally count the occurences). In particular you can do very simple data structure to achieve your goal. Represent each "list" as bag of letters, thus:

```
{A,A,B,C} -> {A:2, B:1, C:1}
{A,B} -> {A:1, B:1}
```

etc. and create basic reverse indexing of some sort, for example keep indexes for each letter separately, sorted by their counts.

Now, when a query comes, like `{A,B} + C` all you do is you search for your data that contains at least 1 A and 1 B (using your indexes), and then estimate probability by computing the fraction of retrived results containing C (or exactly one C) vs. all retrived results (this is a valid probability estimate assuming that your data is a bunch of independent samples from some underlying data-generating distribution).

Alternatively, if your alphabet is very small you can actually precompute all the values `P(C|{A,B})` etc. for all combinations of letters.